# Model.group(:id) throws an error "Select list is not in GROUP BY clause contains non aggregated column "id"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Model.group(:category) in order to get unique records based on category field in Rails 5 application. 
Table data:

```
id catgeory description
1    abc      test
2    abc      test1
3    abc      test2
4    xyz      test
5    xyz       testabc
```

I want records (1,4) as a result. Therefore  I am using Model.group(:category) which works fine for MYSQL whose sql_mode is " " .
Unforunately its throwing an error "SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column  which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by" whose sql_mode is "only_full_group_by".
whats the best way to change the query to match the mode?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try specifying which `id` you want? You could use `MIN(id)`, `MAX(id)` etc.

MySQL supports a non-standard extension to SQL [described here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). To continue using that behavior, you could change the `sql_mode` to `TRADITIONAL` in `config/database.yml`.

Comment: How to use min/ max along with group ? I tried Model.select('MAX(id)').group(:category) which is not working.

Comment: `Model.maximum("id")`

Comment: I want to dsplay complete record based on unique category 
For eg: 
1  abc  test
4 xyz  test

Comment: Yes you can either aggregate all the selected columns, use traditional sql mode. or a query like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group

Comment: Which one is a better option a) changing the sql_mode b) changing the query?

Comment: @jspcal I'm also interested on which should be the best way to go? I upgraded from Rais 4.2 to Rails 5.0.1